# paypal API refund

Tags: api, paypal, nvp

Currently I am working on paypal NVP API,

Our customers have a paypal account. And each customer has given me permission to refund these commands. To do this, they added the name of my API paypal account and they check the option: **issus a refund for a specific transaction**.

they provide me the transaction id for each order ,and my application is supposed to make a refund.

Here is a summary of my program:

```
url = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp'
params =  {
    'USER':'name of my api',
    'PWD': 'pass word of my api',
    'SIGNATURE':'my signature'
     }
 params['METHOD'] = 'RefundTransaction'
 params['VERSION'] = 94
 params['TRANSACTIONID'] = transaction_id
 params['currencyCode'] =  currency
 params['REFUNDTYPE'] = 'Full'
 http.post(url,params)
```

but at the end of execution it returns me:

```
{'res': 'TIMESTAMP=2013%2d11%2d26T15%3a43%3a16Z&CORRELATIONID=848a8035cc65&ACK=Failure& VERSION=51%2e0&BUILD=8620107&L_ERRORCODE0=10007&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Permission%20denied&L_LONGMESSAGE0=You%20do%20not%20have%20permission%20to%20refund%20this%20transaction&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error', 'code': 200}
```

it means that I have not permession to this transaction, While our customers have added me to their paypal account.

How can I address this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best working example to Refund with NVP

```
class PayPalRefund
{
private $API_Username, $API_Password, $Signature, $API_Endpoint, $version;
function __construct($intializeData)
{

    if($intializeData['mode'] == "live")
    {
        $this->API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    }else{
       $this->API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $this->API_Username = $intializeData['username'];
    $this->API_Password = $intializeData['password'];
    $this->Signature = $intializeData['signature'];
    $this->version = "51.0";
}

/**
 * This function actually Sends the CURL Request for Refund
 * @param string - $requestString
 * @return array - returns the response
 */
function sendRefundRequest($requestString)
{
    $this->API_UserName  = urlencode($this->API_Username);
    $this->API_Password  = urlencode($this->API_Password);
    $this->API_Signature = urlencode($this->Signature);

    $this->version = urlencode($this->version);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $reqStr = "METHOD=RefundTransaction&VERSION={$this->version}&PWD={$this->API_Password}&USER={$this->API_UserName}&SIGNATURE={$this->API_Signature}$requestString";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $reqStr);

    // Get response from the server.
    $curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$curlResponse)
        return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"RefundTransaction failed".curl_error($ch)."(".curl_errno($ch).")");

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $curlResponse);

    $aryResponse = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value)
    {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1)
        {
            $aryResponse[$tmpAr[0]] = urldecode($tmpAr[1]);
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($aryResponse)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $aryResponse))
        return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"Invalid HTTP Response for POST request ($reqStr) to {$this->API_Endpoint}");

    return $aryResponse;
}

/**
 * @param array $aryData
 * @return array
 */
function refundAmount($aryData)
{
    if(trim(@$aryData['currencyCode'])=="")
        return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"Currency Code is Missing");
    if(trim(@$aryData['refundType'])=="")
        return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"Refund Type is Missing");
    if(trim(@$aryData['transactionID'])=="")
        return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"Transaction ID is Missing");

    $requestString = "&TRANSACTIONID={$aryData['transactionID']}&REFUNDTYPE={$aryData['refundType']}&CURRENCYCODE={$aryData['currencyCode']}";

    if(trim(@$aryData['invoiceID'])!="")
        $requestString = "&INVOICEID={$aryData['invoiceID']}";

    if(isset($aryData['memo']))
        $requestString .= "&NOTE={$aryData['memo']}";

    if(strcasecmp($aryData['refundType'], 'Partial') == 0)
    {
        if(!isset($aryData['amount']))
        {
            return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"For Partial Refund - It is essential to mention Amount");
        }
        else
        {
            $requestString = $requestString."&AMT={$aryData['amount']}";
        }

        if(!isset($aryData['memo']))
        {
            return array("ERROR_MESSAGE"=>"For Partial Refund - It is essential to enter text for Memo");
        }
    }

    $resCurl = $this->sendRefundRequest($requestString);
    return $resCurl;
}

}
```

Once Class is ready, you can call functions in your Business logic

```
        require_once('PaypalRefund.php');
        /* Refund Type ('Partial', 'Full')*/
        $intializeData = array('email'=>$this->credentials->email,
                              'username'=>$this->credentials->username,
                              'password'=>$this->credentials->password,
                              'signature'=>$this->credentials->signature,
                              'mode'=>'sandbox',  //'live'
                              );
        $aryData['transactionID'] = $data['transaction_id'];
        $aryData['refundType'] = "Full"; //Partial or Full
        $aryData['currencyCode'] = $data['currency_code'];
        $aryData['amount'] = $data['amount'];   //$data['amount'];
        $aryData['memo'] = $data['notes'];


        // Paypal Refund API Call
        $ref = new PaypalRefund($intializeData);
        $aryRes = $ref->refundAmount($aryData);
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($aryRes);echo "</pre>";die;
```

You will get Response upfront as well as on IPN URL (if set).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this was meant to be a **Live** refund, please make sure you are using the correct API [**endpoint**](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints/).

If this was instead a refund transaction to the **Sandbox** Test environment, please make sure that the credentials in use are from your Test Seller Account Sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

When someone grants you third-party API permissions, they grant you permission to make API calls on their behalf.
And since you're calling the `RefundTransaction` API on behalf of someone, you'll need to specify the `SUBJECT` parameter and populate it with the PayPal email address of that person's account.

I.e.

```
params =  {
    'USER':'name of my api',
    'PWD': 'pass word of my api',
    'SIGNATURE':'my signature'
    'SUBJECT':'email of PP account who granted you 3rd party permissions'
     }
```

Because you're not specifying this right now, you're basically trying to refund a transactionID that doesn't belong to your own PayPal account. So it rightly denies you from doing so.